# How to return values from the Object Promise in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to return the values from the object of Promises, the values are printed in the console but when I am displaying it on the HTML, it is showing "OBJECT PROMISE" in place of the returned Value.
My code is

```
const priceConversion = async(data) =>{
    const url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?'
    const response = await  fetch (url)
    const resJSON = await response.json()
    const val =  resJSON['geoplugin_currencySymbol'] + Math.round(data * resJSON['geoplugin_currencyConverter'])
    return val
    
  }
```

The type of val returned is String here. but as soon as it is called from an object, it gives the above mentioned output, i.e "Object Promise"
The code for the Object is

```
  let price = {
      basic:{
          monthly: priceConversion(0),
          annual:priceConversion(0)
        },
        standard:{
            monthly:priceConversion(9),
            annual:priceConversion(4.5),
        },
        premium:{
            monthly:priceConversion(17),
            annual:priceConversion(7)
        }
    }
```

For Document manipulation, I am using the following method

```
let monthly = true
if (monthly === true){
    $("#freeMonthly").empty().text(`${price.basic.monthly}`)
    $("#standardMonthly").empty().text(`${price.standard.monthly}`)
    $("#premiumMonthly").empty().text(`${price.premium.monthly}`)
}
```

It would be really great if anyone could help with this one as I couldn't find any solution that could resolve this issue.
Thank You!

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise; you need to either await it: `await priceConversion(0);` or call `then` method on it: `priceConversion(0).then(result => { /*code*/})`. I suggest you put all your values in an array and use `Promise.all` to get all the converted values in an array which you can then add in the object.

Comment: You have to `await` for `priceConversion` function whenever you're calling it in your code

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 
This is the error, I am getting after putting await before calling the function in Object.

Comment: `await` is only allowed in an `async` function.

Comment: Sir, priceConversion  is an async function, as i have mentioned in the code above.

Comment: If you did this: `await priceConversion(0);`, then this also needs to be in an async function.

Comment: Sir, I did this
     monthly:async() => await priceConversion(0)
After doing 
console.log(price.basic.monthly())
I am still getting the Object Promise

Comment: I can see the string output.

Comment: As i mentioned in my first comment: _"An async function always returns a promise"_ - you created another async function and assigned its return value to "monthly" which is similar to what you had before. You can move the whole `price` object inside an async function and then await `priceConversion(...)`

Comment: Sir, then how would I be able to do document manipulation, I mean how would I be calling price.basic.monthly value,
I Have been trying everything but unable to reach this solution.
 @Yousaf

Comment: Reading about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) can help you understand what you need to do. Once you have read about promises, read: [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to wrap everything in an `async` function and use `await` every time you call your function:

```js
const priceConversion = async(data) => {
  const url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?'
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const resJSON = await response.json()
  const val = resJSON['geoplugin_currencySymbol'] + Math.round(data * resJSON['geoplugin_currencyConverter'])
  return val

}

const calculatePrice = async() => {
  return {
    basic: {
      monthly: await priceConversion(0),
      annual: await priceConversion(0)
    },
    standard: {
      monthly: await priceConversion(9),
      annual: await priceConversion(4.5),
    },
    premium: {
      monthly: await priceConversion(17),
      annual: await priceConversion(7)
    }
  }

}


const main = async() => {
  try {
    console.log("In the main")

    const price = await calculatePrice()

    let monthly = true
    if (monthly === true) {
      $("#freeMonthly").empty().text(`${price.basic.monthly}`)
      $("#standardMonthly").empty().text(`${price.standard.monthly}`)
      $("#premiumMonthly").empty().text(`${price.premium.monthly}`)
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }




}

main()
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="freeMonthly">freeMonthly</div>
  <div id="standardMonthly">standardMonthly</div>
  <div id="premiumMonthly">premiumMonthly</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome. Note that it is actually bad performance because with this code, you have to wait that an API call finishes before doing the next one.

If you want to improve performance (imagine if you have way more possible prices for example), take a look at @Yousaf comment talking about `Promise.all(...)`